# SolrCloud Indexing/Querying without a Smart-Client

Tags: solr, solrnet, solrcloud

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding exactly how indexing and querying would work if I don't have a smart-client available. I'm using SolrNet with C#, which currently doesn't integrate with ZooKeeper.

As a basic example, let's say I have a single collection, split into two shards, replicated across two separate nodes/servers, and I have a standard HTTP load-balancer in front of the servers (a scenario mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8013810/solrnet-how-to-switch-solr-connection-to-another-server-if-the-currently-used-s)). If I use the standard compositeId router, I *believe* that indexing would work without issue and be replicated to both nodes by ZooKeeper behind the scenes. I wouldn't need to worry about which node received the "update" command -- ZooKeeper would handle document routing and replication automatically.

However, in this same scenario, would ZooKeeper handle query routing behind the scenes correctly? Given that I'm using built-in sharding and not custom sharding, would a query request to the load-balancer get routed to the correct shard, or would I have to include *all* known shards in the "shards" parameter (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26533833/solrcloud-load-balancing)) to make sure I don't miss anything? Obviously this would be onerous to maintain as the number of shards grows.

Is seems like custom sharding would provide the greatest efficiency across indexing and querying, although then you run the risk wildly unequal shard sizes. Any thoughts on these matters would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets take the example of a two shard collection, with each shard on a separate node/server.

10.x.x.100:8983/solr/ --> shard 1 / node 1

10.x.x.101:8983/solr/ --> shard 2 / node 2

Using default routing you indexed 100 documents which got split into these two servers and now they have 50 documents each.

If you query any of the two servers for documents, solr will search in both the shards by default. You do not need to specify anything in shards parameter.

So

`10.x.x.100:8983/solr/collection/select?q=solr rocks`

will run this same query on `10.x.x.101:8983/solr/` also and the results returned will be a combination of results from both shards, sorted and ranked by score.

The `&shards` parameter comes into picture when you know which "group" of data is in which shard. For example using the above example, you have custom routing enabled and you use the field "city" to route the documents. For sake of example, lets assume there can be only two values for "city" field. Your documents will be routed to one of the shards based on this field.

On your application side, if you want to specifically query for documents belonging to a city, you can specify the `&shard` parameter, and all the results for the query will be only from that shard.

Comment: I understand what you're saying with regard to custom routing, but I don't know how to implement it. The Solr documentation mentions defining a "router.field", which I believe is what you're suggesting with the idea of the "city" field, but I have no idea where or how to configure that in my collection. I'd appreciate any info regarding that topic you might have. Thanks.

Comment: You can find a lot of information on the Solr Reference Guide. "router.field" is specified when you create a collection. Here is the section on Collections API. Check the Query Parameters table. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Collections+API

Comment: Thanks, @jay, gave it a try, but now it says that the field is unrecognized. Reckon whatever I name "router.field" needs to be included in the schema, right?

Comment: Thanks @jay -- finally got it working with implicit routing and explicit sharding via "router.field".

Comment: So which is custom sharding? CompositeID or Implicit?